# VueJS - Function to display image

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to VueJS and having a hard to on this situation.

*display.vue*

```
<template>
   <img :src="getLogo(logo)" /> 
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  methods: {
    getLogo(logo){
        return '../assets/'+logo;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I got an 404 error on that code.

But I tried not using the `getLogo()` function and it displayed.

```
<template>
   <img src="../assets/logo.svg" /> 
</template>
```

The image structure is:

```
src/assets/logo1.svg
```

*webpack.base.conf.js*

```
test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
loader: 'url-loader',
options: {
 limit: 10000,
 name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
}
```

Anybody here can help me displaying the image by using the `getLogo` function? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I reckon when using `v-bind:src` it should be as follows

```
<img v-bind:src="'../assets/logo.svg'">
<!-- or shorthand -->
<img :src="'../assets/logo.svg'">
```

Notice the `' '`

While using `<img src="../assets/logo.svg" />` you do not need to bind a string, hence that's why it works.

Comment: hi @flyingSmurfs i have tried it but it gave me an error also Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: @DaLoco hard to point out where's the issue, can you put it up JSFiddle?

Comment: your path here ` name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'` is not the same

Comment: shoud I change it to name: utils.assetsPath('assets/[name].[hash:7].[ext] ?

Comment: {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }

Try not to use relative path

Comment: thank you! i just added the file-loader and it loaded already